# Manipulate values of a subset of dataframe columns

Tags: r

I want to standardize a number of columns in a dataframe, but not all columns. The columns to be manipulated are specified in a vector.

To illustrate, take the following simulated dataframe:

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(matrix(sample(100, 36, replace = TRUE), nrow = 12))
```

Defining the two columns to be manipulated (note that the solution should apply to a subset of columns defined by their names, not their dataframe number):

```
variables <- c("X1", "X2")
```

Now I wrote the following loop to standardize the two columns, which throws me an error.

```
for (i in seq_along(variables)) {
  mydf[variables[i]] <- ((mydf[variables[i]] - mean(mydf[variables[i]], na.rm = TRUE)) / sd(mydf[variables[i]], na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

What is the correct way to do this? (I am a beginner to R.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scale`, and you do not need a loop:

```
mydf[variables] <- scale(mydf[variables])
```

Answer (score 0):

standardize feature from mlr package will help you.

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(matrix(sample(100, 36, replace = TRUE), nrow = 12))

colnames(mydf)
library(mlr)
trainTask <- normalizeFeatures(mydf[c( "X1","X2" )],method = "standardize")
```

Comment: Very elegant, however, the solution needs to apply to a subset of columns that is known by column names (not their dataframe position). This was unclear from my question and I edited accordingly.

Comment: updated the solution with specific column names

Comment: Following up my previous comment, replacing `mydf[c(1,2)]` with `mydf[variables]` in your last line of code does what I want.

Comment: you just have to change it to variables thats not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

To get your loop working use `[[` instead of `[` because `mean` and `sd` expect a vector.

```
for (i in seq_along(variables)) {
  mydf[variables[i]] <-
    ((mydf[variables[i]] - mean(mydf[[variables[i]]], na.rm = TRUE)) / sd(mydf[[variables[i]]], na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

But consider to use `scale`, see @SvenHohenstein's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I agree that using `scale` is most straightforward.